# iOS header font

Tags: color, font-identification, ios, hex

Ok, so I am trying to do my first theme, a Tumblr page theme for bookshelf pages. My vision was basing it on iOS iBooks. There are some minor details which I don't know. I really want to  know what the **FONT** of the header bar of iBooks and the **HTML Colour code, hexadecimal or other equivalent codes which will lead me to the same exact colour,** it doesn't have to be websafe.

Thanks.

P.S. Also, if it is a font with many variations, please tell me which variation (e.g. Condensed, Extended, Roman, Normal etc...)

[image: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7388/8804318780_fae6e6e0bf_o.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the iBooks app the following can be found:

```
class="header" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;color:rgb(79,82,84);text-transform:uppercase;line-height:24px;"

class="booktitle" style="font-family:Palatino,Times, Serif;font-size:32px;font-weight:bold;color:rgb(00,00,00);line-height:38px;padding:0 100;"

class="author" style="font-family:Palatino,Times, Serif;font-size:16px;color:rgb(79,82,84);line-height:24px; word-break: break-word;"
```

.plist files contain:

```
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Athelas</string>
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Charter</string>
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Georgia</string>
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Iowan Old Style</string>
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Palatino</string>
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Seravek</string>
<key>fontFamily</key>
<string>Times New Roman</string>
```

(Note: all these fonts are part of the app. I'm not familiar with a couple of them and they could very well be proprietary fonts created by Apple.)

In terms of colors, other than what's indicated above, I think you'll simply have to sample areas of images.

EDIT AFTER IMAGE WAS ADDED: all those items you list are png files within the app, not live text. Therefore there's nothing to be discovered by examining the app contents.

Answer (score 0):

to go into further with the color use [Colorzilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorzilla/) in Firefox with this post like so:

[image]

or Photoshop's color picker tool.  There are many tutorials, like [this](http://www.psawesome.com/tutorials/create-an-i-pad-inspired-bookshelf-using-photoshop), that exist on how to duplicate the shelf.  If you are trying to do this in a timely manner I would possibly just crop out the selected areas.

Answer (score 0):

The font is Helvetica (unfortunately for the interface). Apple has a strange rule of using a customized Myriad for their "branding" but Helvetica in their interfaces. I guess their teams don't like to talk.

As for the colors, just screen grab it and pick out the colors you want. If it's off by a couple points it won't be noticeable in your theme.